# Как лучше размещать виджеты в основном окне?

Tags: python, qt, gui, pyqt, qlayout

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше размещать виджеты в основном окне в лэйауты? или просто выкинуть их на основную форму? 
И если в лэйауты, то как именно? (если можно, с примерами).

И вообще какие правила "хорошего тона" существуют при создании приложений в Qt?
Где про них можно почитать? Или если можно вкратце, то буду рад ответам тут.

Comment: Не существует никаких правил. Отталкиваться надо только от требований к задаче, личного вкуса и опыта. Читать надо доку и эспериментировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Layout management**](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/) — это то, как мы размещаем виджеты в окне приложения. 
Мы можем разместить наши виджеты, используя абсолютное позиционирование
или классы компоновки Qt.
**Управление компоновкой с помощью менеджеров компоновки является предпочтительным
способом организации наших виджетов.**

**`Абсолютное позиционирование`**

Программист указывает положение и размер каждого виджета в пикселях. 
Когда вы используете абсолютное позиционирование,
мы должны понимать следующие ограничения:

- Размер и положение виджета не меняются, если мы меняем размер окна.
- Приложения могут выглядеть по-разному на разных платформах
- Изменение шрифтов в нашем приложении может испортить макет
- Если мы решим изменить наш макет, мы должны полностью переделать наш макет,
  что утомительно и требует много времени.

[**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Система компоновки Qt предоставляет простой и мощный способ автоматического
размещения дочерних виджетов внутри виджета, чтобы убедиться,
что они эффективно используют доступное пространство.

Qt включает в себя набор классов управления расположением,
которые используются для описания расположения виджетов в пользовательском интерфейсе приложения. 
Эти макеты автоматически размещают виджеты и изменяют их размер при изменении объема
доступного для них пространства, гарантируя, что они будут последовательно расположены, а пользовательский интерфейс в целом останется пригодным для использования.

Все подклассы `QWidget` могут использовать макеты для управления своими дочерними элементами.
Функция `QWidget::setLayout()` применяет макет к виджету.

Когда макет устанавливается на виджет таким образом, он берет на себя следующие задачи:

- Расположение дочерних виджетов
- Разумные размеры по умолчанию для окон
- Разумные минимальные размеры окон
- Обработка изменения размера
- Автоматические обновления при изменении содержимого:

  - Размер шрифта, текст или другое содержимое дочерних виджетов
  - Скрытие или отображение дочернего виджета
  - Удаление дочерних виджетов

**Классы компоновки Qt**

Классы компоновки Qt были разработаны для рукописного кода C++,
что позволяет для простоты указывать измерения в пикселях,
поэтому их легко понять и использовать.
Код, сгенерированный для форм, созданных с помощью Qt Designer,
также использует классы макета.
Qt Designer полезно использовать при экспериментировании с дизайном формы,
поскольку он позволяет избежать циклов компиляции, компоновки и выполнения,
обычно связанных с разработкой пользовательского интерфейса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[**Класс QLayout**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html) является базовым классом менеджеров геометрии.

Я предлагаю вам больше узнать об управлении макетами,
а также [**поэкспериментировать с ними в дизайнере Qt**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html),
чтобы лучше понять, как управление макетами работает в Qt.

Основные макеты Qt (grid/сетка и boxed/прямоугольник) настолько же просты,
насколько и эффективны.

Макеты Qt допускают вложение макетов:
например, вы можете добавить горизонтальный макет к вертикальному,
если вам не нравится расположение строк/столбцов, которое обеспечивает QGridLayout.

и т.д.

---

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog,
        QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, 
        QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, 
        QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout)


class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons  = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()

        self.createMenu()
        self.createHorizontalGroupBox()
        self.createGridGroupBox()
        self.createFormGroupBox()

        bigEditor = QTextEdit()
        bigEditor.setPlainText("Этот виджет занимает все оставшееся пространство "
                "в макете верхнего уровня.")

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.gridGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(bigEditor)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Basic Layouts")

    def createMenu(self):
        self.menuBar = QMenuBar()

        self.fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        self.exitAction = self.fileMenu.addAction("E&xit")
        self.menuBar.addMenu(self.fileMenu)

        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.accept)

    def createHorizontalGroupBox(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox("Horizontal layout")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        for i in range(Dialog.NumButtons):
            button = QPushButton("Button %d" % (i + 1))
            layout.addWidget(button)

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createGridGroupBox(self):
        self.gridGroupBox = QGroupBox("Grid layout")
        layout = QGridLayout()

        for i in range(Dialog.NumGridRows):
            label = QLabel("Line %d:" % (i + 1))
            lineEdit = QLineEdit()
            layout.addWidget(label,    i + 1, 0)
            layout.addWidget(lineEdit, i + 1, 1)

        self.smallEditor = QTextEdit()
        self.smallEditor.setPlainText("Этот виджет занимает около двух третей "
            "макета сетки. \n Смотрим соотношение `setColumnStretch`!")

        layout.addWidget(self.smallEditor, 0, 2, 5, 1)   

        # QGridLayout.setColumnStretch(column, stretch)
        # Устанавливает растягивающий коэффициент столбца столбца для растягивания. 
        # Первый столбец - номер 0.
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 10)      
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 20)      
        self.gridGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Line 1:"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Строка 2, длинный текст:"), QComboBox())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Line 3:"), QSpinBox())
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все, что утащено с других сайтов, я бы завернул в цитаты, чтобы было понятно, что это не ваш текст...